# Java script is not writing the logs into file but showing the logs on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

I am trying to create a logfile where I want to write everything info/error/warn etc.

Below is my code where I can see the logs on console but the script is not writing into a file:

```js
var log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    cleanupLogs: {
      type: 'file',
      filename: 'QuoteCleanup.log'
    },
    console: {
      type: 'console'
    }
  },
  categories: {
    default: {
      appenders: ['console'],
      level: 'trace'
    }
  }
});

var log = log4js.getLogger();
```

Comment: Can you show us an example on how you use your `log` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this devtools snippet shown below to create a console.save method. It creates a FileBlob from the input, and then automatically downloads it.

***Edited***
I just edited my answer try this one and tell if this works for you

```js
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    everything: {
      type: 'file',
      filename: 'QuoteCleanup.log'
    }
  },
  categories: {
    default: {
      appenders: ['everything'],
      level: 'debug'
    }
  }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.debug('I will be logged in QuoteCleanup.log');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i would like to know what am i doing wrong in my code

Comment: its a bit hard to get that without seeing a running code snippet or example.

Comment: If you try to create a javascript with my code it will work and it is just printing the logs to console but not writing in the file

Comment: @AnujVaishampayan i updated my answer please check if that simplest way works or not?

Comment: It worked perfectly :), thanks a lot. may I know what i was doing wrong?

Comment: Glad it works for you, your configurations were wrong see here for help https://log4js-node.github.io/log4js-node/file.html , additionally do select the right answer so that other might also get benefit who are having the same problem